# What are the restrictions on modifying an object through a pointer to its byte representation in C++?

Tags: c++, types, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, c++20

I was confused by the following paragraph about type aliasing from cppreference [(source)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

*Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true:*

- *AliasedType and DynamicType are similar.*
- *AliasedType is the (possibly cv-qualified) signed or unsigned variant of DynamicType.*
- ***AliasedType is `std::byte`, `char`, or `unsigned char`: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.***

Consider I have an object of a trivial type (such as a scalar) whose size is larger than 1 byte. In what ways (if at all), am I allowed to modify the byte representation of the object through a pointer to a different type without invoking undefined behaviour? For example:

```
int x = 5, y = 10;
std::byte* x_bytes = reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(&x);

//#1: replacing the entire representation:
std::memcpy(x_bytes, &y, sizeof(int));

//#2: changing a random byte in the representation:
x_bytes[0] = (std::byte)3;
```

Are both of these operations allowed, or only #1?
The problem is that I don't know how to interpret the paragraph I quoted. The three bullets are exceptions to the rule that *"Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value [...] the behavior is undefined"*, which would imply that both reading and writing are allowed if one of the bullets is applicable. However, the third bullet only mentions the *"examination of the object representation"*, which implies read-only access.
I tried to find an appropriate standard page describing this problem in more detail, but I haven't been able to, so this was all I had that was relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Are both of these operations allowed

Yes. There is no rule saying that you must modify all or nothing. Modifying a single byte is allowed.

---

> However, the third bullet only mentions the "examination of the object representation", which implies read-only access.

The standard rule doesn't use such wording. This is the rule from the latest draft:

> [basic.lval]
>
> If a program attempts to **access** the stored value of an object through a glvalue whose type is not similar to one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object, or
> - a char, unsigned char, or std​::​byte type.

Access is defined as:

> [defns.access]
>
> ⟨execution-time action⟩ read or modify the value of an object

---

Of course, modifying bytes by their index-order is quite dubious from portability perspective, since different systems store their bytes in different orders, and thus you would be modifying a byte with different order of significance on different systems.

Different behaviour on different systems is often undesirable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, especially for linking the standard page.

Comment: There are also [basic.life]/1.5 and /5 which talk about **reusing** the storage; [work is underway](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1839r2.pdf) to establish that the bytes act like subobjects so as not to end the lifetime of the ordinary object.