# Type punning a stream of bytes into valid objects with memcpy

Tags: c++, memory, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, type-punning

Let us say I have a file in which I have stored the memory representation of an array of `uint32_t` as bytes. Now I read the file and would like to reconstruct the old array without incurring UB.

```
uint32_t arr[4] = {0,1,2,3};
write_to_file("arr.txt", arr, 4); //write to file

std::byte* buf = read_array("arr.txt"); //read it back in, buf is a 16 byte buffer 

uint32_t new_arr[4]; //this should contain what arr contains by end of the program

for(int ii = 0; ii < 4; ++ii)
    new_arr[ii] = bytes_to_uint32(buf+(4*ii)); //what should bytes_to_uint32(std::byte*) look like?
```

Now this is clearly UB:

```
uint32_t bytes_to_uint(std::byte* ptr){
    return *((uint32_t*)ptr); //strict alias violation
}
```

and as far as I know this is also UB:

```
uint32_t bytes_to_uint(std::byte* ptr){
    uint32_t ret;
    std::byte* bytes = (std::byte*) &ret; 

    for(int ii = 0; ii < 4; ++ii)
        *bytes++ = *ptr++; // If I understand correctly, reading out bytes of any object 
                           // is fine but not writing back

    return ret;
}
```

Also bit_cast won't work since there is no living object at "ptr" of the same size as `uint32_t` to cast from.

A lot of posters say this is fine:

```
uint32_t bytes_to_uint(std::byte* ptr){
    uint32_t ret;
    memcpy(&ret, ptr, 4); //This should end ret's lifetime since it is overwritten with
                          //the implicit byte objects created by memcpy, correct?
    return ret;
}
```

Isn't the memcpy call equivalent to just reusing the storage of "ret" to construct an array of 4 `std::byte` objects (C++20 Implicit object creation)? If so, "ret" is no longer a valid `uint32_t` and the return statement is UB?

EDIT: Apparently I was wrong on the second implementation(byte by byte copy) [What are the restrictions on modifying an object through a pointer to its byte representation in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67621227/what-are-the-restrictions-on-modifying-an-object-through-a-pointer-to-its-byte-r)
But still, the memcpy is confusing to me, since memcpy has some extra powers(compared to a for-loop bytewise copy) like implicit object creation.

Comment: @EvgsupportsModeratorStrike Yes, but not the other way round. You cannot simply cast a pointer of std::byte to a pointer of uint32_t and use it as such. Alignment is obviously also an issue here.

Comment: See [std::bitcast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) (C++20) and [std:::start_lifetime_as](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as) (C++23). But in general, I don't trust to build anything on type punning streams (you never know if things like endianess/padding/sizeof(int) are the same on begin and end of stream).

Comment: *Isn't the memcpy call equivalent to just reusing the storage of "ret" to construct an array of 4 std::byte objects(C++20 Implicit object creation)?*  **Yes**, the memcpy call is *not* equivalent to just reusing the storage of `ret` to construct an array of 4 `std::byte` objects.